# How to be informed if user signed out or revoked access from provider in FirebaseUI Auth?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, twitter-login

I'm developing an android app that has login with Twitter and email. I implemented **com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:5.0.0**. Then i'm checking if user is already logged in, if not starting login activity provided by FirebaseUI Auth:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build());


    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(true)
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
    } else {

        for (UserInfo profile : firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getProviderData()) {
            if (profile.getProviderId().equals(TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)) {
                // UID specific to the provider
                String uid = profile.getUid();

                String name = profile.getDisplayName();
                String email = profile.getEmail();
                Uri photoUrl = profile.getPhotoUrl();
            }
        }
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
}
```

With this approach, i can login with my twitter account and claim my basic twitter informations like name,email,photo URL.
But when i go to the original **Twitter android app > Settings > Account > Apps and Sessions and revoke access** to my app and then try to open my app again, i can still claim my twitter informations. 
I want to know when user revoked access to my app and whenever they do that, i want them to logout.
I wonder how i can overcome this issue and i also wonder if this is the best practice for this situation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During Firebase authentication, a token is generated for security. As soon as the token is provided to a user, it remains valid until it expires. If you revoke the access from your Twitter account, it doesn't mean that the token is expired. It simply means that if the user signs out, he will **not** be able again to use the Twitter account for another authentication since the access was revoked. Unfortunately, there is no way you can remotely force a user to be signed out as it is also impossible you can somehow access the user's device and remove the token. Any sign out is needed to take place on the device that the user is signed in on.

So even if you disable the user's account from Firebase console, the user may continue to have access for up to an hour. If this not what you want, there is a workaround, in which you can add and maintain in Cloud Firestore or in Firebase Realtime database, a list of "revoked" users and then check against that using [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules).

As an example, in Realtime database, a revoked list if user ids might look like this:

```
revoked
  |
  --- uidOne: true
  |
  --- uidTwo: true
```

And then the corresponding security rule might look like this:

```
".read": "auth.uid !== null && !root.child('revoked').child(auth.uid).exists()"
```

Comment: I want to be informed from Firebase Auth when user revoke access from their Twitter app. Even they revoke access to my app firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() returns their twitter informations. But you said that it's impossible. Did i get it right?

Comment: *I want to be informed from Firebase Auth when user revokes access from their Twitter app*. Firebase Auth doesn't offer you this information. *Even they revoke access to my app firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() returns their twitter informations.* That's the correct behavior. This is happening until the token expires. So the only option that you have is using Security Rules, as explained in my answer above.